# Phone Data Access in android, iphone using Flex Builder

Tags: apache-flex, air, adobe, flexbuilder

Is it possible to access phone data like (Contact,Message) in android,Iphone using Flash Builder Mobile Development app  .... If It's Possible using Adobe air so tell me ..

thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the underlying operating system exposes that data, you can access it using a [Native Extension](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/mobileapps/WSe4e4b720da9dedb5-4aefe03513238d8a1b8-8000.html).  You may have to write your own Native Extension to do that, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can call these API's -
Accelerometer

GPS

Camera

Microphone

To store data-

Sql Lite Datebases

OS Interactions-

Text Message

Email

Call

Example-

```
protected function sendMessage(event:MouseEvent):void {
var message:String = "";
message +="sms:";
message+ = sendTo.text;
navigateToURL ( new URLRequest (message));
}
```

This should open your messaging app. However the data you to want to read is mostly going to be protected. You can write a Native Extension though and plug Flex into it.